# Slowly being introduced to Propositional Logic…did I do this right?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I want to make sure I'm getting the concept down. The question is asking

(P'-->Q') [AND] Q [AND] (P-->R) --> R

Here is what I did:

1. (P'-->Q') = (Hypothesis)
2. Q = (Hypothesis)
3. (P-->R) = (Hypothesis)
4. P = (1,2, modus tollens)
5. R = (3,4, modus ponens)

Is that correct? What I'm struggling to understand is which statement I should prove first and how I know if I'm including enough steps and all that and I just wanted to see if I got a good grasp of this concept. I will obviously do more examples but I just want to see if I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: Looks right to me~

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   That is okay.

$$\begin{align}&\begin{array}{rll}
1. & (P'\to Q') & \text{(Hypothesis)}
\\
2. & Q &\text{  (Hypothesis)}
\\
3. & (P\to R) &\text{  (Hypothesis)}
\\
4. & P &\text{ (1,2, modus tollens)}
\\
5. & R &\text{ (3,4, modus ponens)}
\end{array}
\\[2ex]
\therefore\quad & (P'\to Q') , Q , (P\to R) \vdash R\end{align}$$

PS: This site uses MathJax to format and display mathematics.  Here's a [basic tutorial and quick reference.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)